# Unable to access user's email by using facebook login

Tags: facebook

i want to use facebook login api in my website.

But it response me only "name" and "id", not email.

[image]

And there is my facebook api code:

```
<script>
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/zh_TW/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>   
<script>
    // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        console.log('statusChangeCallback');
        console.log(response);
        // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
        // app know the current login status of the person.
        // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
        // for FB.getLoginStatus().
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // Logged into your app and Facebook.
            testAPI();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
            //document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
            //  'into this app.';
        } else {
            // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
            // they are logged into this app or not.
            //document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
            //  'into Facebook.';
        }
    }

    function facebooklogin() {
        FB.login(function (response) {
            // handle the response
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // Logged into your app and Facebook.
                testAPI();
            }
        }, { scope: 'email,public_profile' });
    }

    // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
    // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
    // code below.
    function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    }

    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'myappid',
            cookie: true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
            // the session
            xfbml: true,  // parse social plugins on this page
            version: 'v2.4' // use version 2.3
        });

        // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
        // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
        // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
        // the callback you provide.  They can be:
        //
        // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
        // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
        // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
        //    your app or not.
        //
        // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

        //FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        //  statusChangeCallback(response);
        //});

    };

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
    // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
    function testAPI() {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function (response) {
            console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
            window.location = "facebooklogin.aspx?name=" + response.name + '&gender=' + response.gender + '&locale=' + response.locale + '&id=' + response.id + '&email=' + response.email;
            //document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_hfFBInfo').value = response.name + ',' + response.gender + ',' + response.link + ',' + response.locale + ',' + response.timezone + ',' + response.verified + ',' + response.id + ',' + response.email;
            //document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_hfFBInfo').click();
        });
    }
</script>
```

You can see the scope is 'email,public_profile', and the popout window also checked the email column.

[image]

Can you please tell me what's wrong with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify each field you want to have returned. Have a look at the answer at

- [Facebook JS SDK's FB.api('/me') method doesn't return the fields i expect in Graph API v2.4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584850/cant-get-full-data-with-fb-api-me/32585470#32585470)

Comment: I change code to 
"FB.api('/me', 'get', { fields: 'id,name,gender,email' }, function (response) {"
it works. Thanks.