# Facebook login does not send email

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, token

I've check over the web but couldn't find a solution.

When asking for permission `https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=<valid_token>`returns

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "permission": "user_friends",
         "status": "granted"
      },
      {
         "permission": "email",
         "status": "granted"
      },
      {
         "permission": "public_profile",
         "status": "granted"
      }
   ]
}
```

`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=<valid_token>` and `https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/?access_token=<valid_token>`
returns

```
{
   "name": "my_name",
   "id": "my_id"
}
```

I tried `https://graph.facebook.com/me?scope=email&access_token=my_token` same result

I've granted these permission but why doesn't the api return those?

Answer (score 0):

As @Tobi suggested according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32585470/4335588) post all fields need to be specified individually.

`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=<token>&fields=name,last_name,email`