# laravel socialite facebook logging not getting user details

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I have been trying to get user details from facebook login using socialite but only getting name and id it worked in my old facebook app(api 2.0) it has changed from v2.4 we need to manually specify fields but how we do in laravel socialite any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook JS SDK's FB.api('/me') method doesn't return the fields i expect in Graph API v2.4+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584850/facebook-js-sdks-fb-api-me-method-doesnt-return-the-fields-i-expect-in-gra)

Answer (score 0):

Yes just solved it by updating FacebookProvider.php
https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/2.0/src/Two/FacebookProvider.php