# login with facebook with database

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

in my localhost site i am using login with facebook feature and it's working fine but now i want to store user details to my database so, i put some code in facebook SDK file fb-callback.php like...

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'app_id', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
  'app_secret' => 'app_secret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  if ($helper->getError()) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
    echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
    echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
    echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
  } else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    echo 'Bad request';
  }
  exit;
}

// Logged in
echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
var_dump($tokenMetadata);

// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId("app_id"); // Replace {app-id} with    your app id
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
//$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
  // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
  try {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
  } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
    exit;
  }

  echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
  var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
}

$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
$fbApp = new Facebook\FacebookApp('app_id',  'app_secret');
$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest($fbApp, $accessToken, 'GET', '/me');
try {
  $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
include "config.php";
$query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '".$graphNode['name']."', '".$graphNode['email']."')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result) {
// User is logged in with a long-lived access token.
// You can redirect them to a members-only page.
header('location:index.php');
}
else{
  echo "Problem In Login";
}
?>
```

but it inserting only name in database not email. Please help me.

Comment: `Facebook\Facebook` class does not have an `api` method.

Comment: so, what should i use to insert username and email in my database?

Comment: A method that that class does support – so go check the docs.

Comment: i made change upon your instruction and now i can insert name in database but not email please help me.i also change code above.

Comment: That’s likely because you did not _get_ an email value from the API (which you should have realized during your debugging efforts!) – you need to _ask_ for the email field, see f.e. http://stackoverflow.com/q/32584850/1427878

Comment: (And of course you need to ask for the appropriate permission first.)

Comment: what should i do to get user_likes?

Comment: You mean the permission of that name? Ask for it during login.

Comment: i am asking with user_likes but it's likes...i got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's done with this.

```
$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
$fbApp = new Facebook\FacebookApp('1014758295283866', 'b1a98e587c8bef98dfb273db67214afb');
$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest($fbApp, $accessToken, 'GET', '/me', ['fields' => 'id,name,email']);
try {
     $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
include "config.php";
$query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '".$graphNode['name']."', '".$graphNode['email']."')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result) {
// User is logged in with a long-lived access token.
// You can redirect them to a members-only page.
header('location:index.php');
}
else{
  echo "Problem In Login";
}
```