# cordova facebook login FB.api call not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I am working on cordova facebook login, with the [phonegap-facebook-plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin),

I am using the following function after checking the login status of the user with `FB.getLoginStatus`

```
function processFacebook(token) {
  FB.api('/me', 'get', {
    access_token: token
  }, function(response) {
    alert(response);
  });
}
```

but, I am unable to receive any response.
Can anybody point out where I am going wrong?
I took the reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584850/facebook-js-sdks-fb-api-me-method-doesnt-return-the-fields-i-expect-in-gra?answertab=votes#tab-top) , but the method seems not to work.
Here's the link to the original [index.js](https://github.com/souparno/FacebookPluginCordova/blob/not-working-code/www/js/index.js) and [index.html](https://github.com/souparno/FacebookPluginCordova/blob/not-working-code/www/index.html) file

Comment: the alert work , but with no response !! or it doesn't work at all

Comment: no, the function is not called at all

Comment: debug it and see if you get anything in the console. cordova apps are pretty easy to debug anyway.

Comment: how will i debug this? using logcat? @luschn

Comment: works with cordovba apps too: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this stuff.**

**To get Access Token.**

```
var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
        alert("UserInfo: ", userData);
        facebookConnectPlugin.getAccessToken(function(token) {
        alert("Token: " + token);
    });
}
```

**Get user Profile data.**

```
var fbLogin = function() {
    facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_location"],
        function(response) {
            console.log("Login Response :" + JSON.stringify(response));
            //alert("Login Response :" + JSON.stringify(response))
            this.authId = response.authResponse.userID;
            if (response.status == "connected") {
                facebookConnectPlugin.api("/" + response.authResponse.userID, ["public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_location"],
                    function(result) {
                        this.email = result.email;
                        this.firstname = result.first_name;
                        this.lastname = result.last_name;
                        this.birthdate = result.birthday;
                        this.city = result.location.name;
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        alert("Failed: " + error);
                    });
            }
        },
        function(response) {
            alert("Other Response : " + JSON.stringify(response))
        });
}
```

`It will give you all the Relevant details of User Profile.`

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, I am working on this, can you also tell me how do you find the user parameter names? because the graph api explorer seems not to work https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.6

Comment: @souparnomajumder I didn't get you ! can you pls explain more.

Comment: how did you know that "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_location", will be the parameter names? the facebook graph api explorer (the link that i have mentioned in the comment) doesnot seem to work, so if i am to include other user parameter int how am i to find that out?

Comment: @souparnomajumder That all parameters are mentioned in plugins it self which you are using you don't need to check it for official development. this plugins are created using that all stuffs so it contains all the required functionalities of official development. you just need to use this try and check.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
alert("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
facebookConnectPlugin.getAccessToken(function(token) {
    alert("Token: " + token);
}, function(err) {
    alert("Could not get access token: " + err);
});
```

}