# How can I get the image source (url) based on facebook image id using Facebook API for JS

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I got a website where I make the user log-in into the App, and he/she would be able to access all their photos within my page and edit them.

The way I get the albums is this:

```
FB.api(
  "/me/albums",
     function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
          ...
        }
     }
);
```

Then after getting the list of album IDs, I iterate through them to get their respective photos by doing:

```
FB.api(
  "/"+albumId+"/photos",
     function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
          ...
        }
     }
);
```

This would return an array of objects containing the image IDs.

I thought it would be by using `FB.api("/imageId", function(){})` but that returns the same image object with the id.

I want to get the image source/full path so I could add them inside an HTML IMG tag. But I'm still having problems with it.

I saw that there was some way of doing it by getting a "JSON" from this URL:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/"+photoId
```

But that throws me a authentication error for example if I try to get it using AJAX (might be because ajax doesn't contain the authentication that FB object does)

How can I get that result ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to ask for the fields you want, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32585470/1427878

Comment: But i would like to get the URL for a specific photo ID, that looks like it returns what i already have... if i sned user_photos for field, it will return all the photo IDs, right?

Comment: _“if i sned user_photos for field”_ – what? And what information are you really looking for – the URL to the photo on Facebook, so that users can view it there? The URL of the image ion Facebook’s CDN, so that you can use it in an `img` element on your site? Or …?

Comment: sorry typo error, i meant to say, if i "send". I currently have all the users albums and photos with their IDs. I would like to find a way to display those images in my website, is there any way to get the absolute path to the image?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation already for which fields are available for Photo objects? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo

Comment: You were totally right, yea. I found a way based on the documentation. I had to add an extra parameter for fields as an object { fields : "..." } and that seemed to work fine :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So after getting some documentation links from @CBroe, I found that by doing this

```
FB.api(
    "/"+photoId, {"fields" : "images"},
    function (response) {
         if (response && !response.error) {
             console.log(response)
         }
    }
);
```

By sending the field "images", it would return all the absolute paths to the different sizes of that specific image.

If you want a 100x100px thumbnail, you can pass "picture" as the field.