# Facebook long access token does not yield results anymore

Tags: ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I went to this site - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ - to extend the expiry, but sadly now queries dont yield the same result anymore.

Earlier with the short term access token, I ran `@likes = graph.get_object(company)["likes"]` and it used to perfectly return the number of likes for any company page,
But after generating the extended access token it just does not work. It only returns the full company name and its id.

How to access all the other attributes? Is there any different calls?

Comment: You need to ask for the fields you want, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32585470/1427878 (How to do that with the framework you are using, should be in its documentation.)

Comment: Hey I had been playing with it for some while, after your help and i got one last issue - http://stackoverflow.com/q/39047240/2096740