# Rails koala get page and page post insights

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

Getting insights for page posts returning `[]`

This is for the adidas page
`pp graph.get_object("182162001806727/insights/")`
It generally returns fields for country data and nothing for `page_impressions` or `page_engagement`, etc

Even though the docs mention that Insights are generated for a psot/page with more than 30 likes, but still nothing.

Infact, insights for the first post of Adidas page returns absolutely nothing
`pp graph.get_object("182162001806727_1189840444372206/insights")`
or
`graph.get_connections('182162001806727_1189840444372206', 'insights/page_impressions_frequency_distribution', period: 'week'`

even though it has high amount of likes and comments, if you check their feed.

**So, what is the correct method or is it even possible or publicly available.**

And, for pages, is the page_impression/engagement data available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/insights#reading:

> Permissions:
>   - Any valid access token can be used for publicly available metrics (currently **page_fans_country** or **page_storytellers_by_country**)
>   - A user access token with read_insights permission can retrieve metrics for all pages and domains owned by this user.
>   - A page access token with read_insights permission can retrieve all metrics for that Page.

Those two permissions highlighted in bold are the only two publicly available ones. For everything else, you need an admin user token or a page token.

Comment: So to paraphrase, if the user has authorized the app, ie, OAuth, then the app can get other insights, right?

Comment: Yes, for those objects that the user has the right to see insights for.