# Get About us, photos and other details of facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to get all information of facebook page like about us ,photos, reviews ,likes etc using facebook graph API but unable to get the proper response.

Can anyone please help in that?

Comment: what did you try? show some code so that SO people can know and tell you whats wrong you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can find information about your question on this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page

Comment: Thanks for answer but when I try to use GET /v2.8/{page-id} API then I only get id and name nothing else maybe this is because I don't have correct access rights for that page but is there any other way to scrape about us , likes and photos of that facebook page because this is very important for my project.
Here is an example when I try to scrape About us of this https://www.facebook.com/mickeykitchensaltlake/ facebook page then only thing which I get is ID and name of this facebook page and I am using javascript SDk for using facebook graph API.

Comment: The official way is to use the facebook API. Now, if the thing you are looking for isn't included there, you can parse the whole html code of the page using php to get what you want, which is a little complex and involves many searching. It can be done with a php library like simpleHTMLDOM: [link]http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ . First open the html code of the facebook page to see where the variables you want are located and then parse it using the simpleHTMLDOM to get those variables. IMPORTANT: If you gain money from this, i am afraid it is not very legal. It's your responsibility.

Comment: _“then I only get id and name nothing else”_ - why that is and what you do about it, is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32585470/1427878