# Graph API Facebook doesn't return correct statistics of a webpage

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am using the next piece of javascript code to get the facebook share's number of my webpage:

```
FB.api("/", { "id": urlOfMyPage }, response => shares = response.share.share_count;);
```

The response returned is "{id: urlOfMyPage}".

I called the same webservice at [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and received the response that I need. After this action I am able to use the code above to get the statistics that I need.

Someone had the same problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook JS SDK's FB.api('/me') method doesn't return the fields i expect in Graph API v2.4+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584850/facebook-js-sdks-fb-api-me-method-doesnt-return-the-fields-i-expect-in-gra)

Comment: Since API v2.4, you need to specify the fields you want (see the duplicate) - most likely it worked in Graph API Explorer, because you were unknowingly using an older API version there.

Comment: I added the field "fields" but it didn't work. The strange here is that after using graph api explorer I receive what I what: {id:urlOfMyPage, share:{share_count:1,comment_count:0}}.

Comment: There is no field named `fields`. // Please share a link to the exact request you are making in Graph API Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

It was a scraping problem. I resolved the problem forcing the scrap when I share the page.

```
FB.api("/", "post", { id: urlOfMyPage, scrape: true }, response => console.log('scrapped'));
```