# Get user posts details from Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get my Facebook posts details which i have posted (details like tagged location, likes, comment and etc) by using a JavaScript app hosted in a server.I was able to get user basic information like first name, age, profile pic and etc. I used following code to extract posts details but i was not able to fetch those data.

```
FB.api("/me/posts", function(response) {
console.log(response);
}); 

FB.api("/me?fields=posts.limit(50)", function(response) {
console.log(response);
});
```

I'm receiving a output like following

```
Object {id: "*************"}
```

I host my on AWS. Is there is any need to take any permission from Facebook to get those data or what is the mistake that i'm doing? Thank you

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_posts

Comment: @suraj- I have gone through that documentation. But i'm not having clear idea about this statement "If your app requests this permission Facebook will have to review how your app uses it".

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit if your app requests user details other than name,email profile, you need to submit your app to facebook for review

Comment: also see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review

Comment: You also need to ask for the fields you want; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/32584850/1427878 for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need permission in order to get information like post, feed etc.
Go to graph API explorer and get the permission using get user access token, there you will be provided with a bunch of permissions parameters.

So you can choose one and can retrieve for your app.