# facebook through curl auth was failed

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl

I use FB authorization through curl. Till now during a half an year All have been working well. But during the last couple of days I have found a message:

```
    [{"error":{"message":"This_authorization_code_has_been_used_","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"HuUHKJv\/zGu"}}] =>
    $params = array(
        'client_id'     => FACEBOOK_ID,
        'redirect_uri'  => PATH_ROOT.REDIRECT_URI,
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope'         => 'email, user_birthday'
);
<a href="<?php echo FACEBOOK_OAUTH . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params))?>" class="facebook-icon-edit">Change</a>



callback:

if(isset($_GET['code']) and strlen($_GET['code']) > 100){

        $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token';
        $tokenInfo = null;

        $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
                . "client_id=" . FACEBOOK_ID . "&redirect_uri=" .      urlencode(PATH_ROOT.REDIRECT_URI)
                . "&client_secret=" . FACEBOOK_SECRET . "&code=" . $_GET['code'];
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $token_url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            parse_str(curl_exec($curl), $tokenInfo);
            curl_close($curl);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($tokenInfo);
        echo "</pre>";
///the three last rows get the message written above
```

Comment: Can you post some code that demonstrates what you are doing, and detail how it is being called, as well as anything pertinent about your server setup (eg any reverse proxies / redirects / rewriting etc)?

Comment: The error message in your question is incomplete. Post the entire message.

Comment: If this started happening a few days ago, then it is most likely related to the API v2.2 shutdown. Since API v2.3, the format in which the access token is returned from that endpoint has changed, it now returns JSON. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42994019/1427878

Comment: It`s strange but in developers.facebook.com i found version API v2.3

Comment: it long before  in account in developers.facebook.com as version API v2.3 was set

Answer (score 0):

The source of error was that, so far, responce from facebook was a string.
and now bacame as a json one.
so I change

```
parse_str(curl_exec($curl), $tokenInfo);
```

to

```
$tokenInfo= curl_exec($curl);
$tokenInfo = json_decode($tokenInfo, true);
```

message: this authorization code has been used

this message was appeared may be for a reason of several applying to one page