# Error in callAPI(query, token)

Tags: r, facebook

I had tried to access my FB token using the preliminary code shown by pablo over here :

https://github.com/pablobarbera/Rfacebook

However I get the following error message :

```
Error in callAPI(query, token) : 
  An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

I used this code:

```
fb_oauth <- fbOAuth(app_id="14025", app_secret="5fdb6ef5776",extended_permissions = TRUE)

save(fb_oauth, file="fb_oauth")

load("fb_oauth")
```

I understand that I am not having access using my token despite authentication completion. Could someone please help.

Comment: Facebook has recently shut down API v2.2, so all apps must use at least use v2.3 now - and in that, the format in which the access token is returned has changed, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994019/facebook-graph-api-not-work-from-2-2-to-2-3 - so you might need to update your package.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix is just remove **type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"** 
 from fbOauth.R in RFacebook package. Because now Facebook returns response in JSON format.

Comment: I can confirm that this works to solve OP's problem.

Comment: I have a similar problem with the instaR package. Would it be a similar solution for this type of question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75264948/access-token-not-working-to-get-followers-on-instagram-api