# Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, opencart2.x

I am using a module on **opencart 2.0.1.1** named **Social Login Free** and using **facebook-php-3.2** Login with facebook was working correctly but now when a user clicks on login with facebook it takes it correctly to the
facebook oath login dialog and when user clicks continue it returns this error
**Authentification failed. The user has canceled the authentication or the provider refused the connection. Ooophs, we got an error: Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id.**  I have tried several solutions but failed.

```
  public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 60,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-3.2',
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false
  );

protected $trustForwarded = true;
protected $allowSignedRequest = false;
```

Nothing is working please help.

Update :

It is not a duplicate as in my case I had to upgrade facebook-php-sdk to v5 and it solved my problem! tada...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook upgraded api graph version from 2.2 to 2.3 what i did read so far is that the access token is now different than before and json encoded. The change did happen on 03.25.2017 I have the same problem with hybridauth but no idea how to solve. I hope that helps.

[facebook graph api not work from 2.2 to 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994019/facebook-graph-api-not-work-from-2-2-to-2-3)