# flynsarmy-sociallogin (Facebook api) in octoberCMS - Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, octobercms

I'm using octoberCMS based on Laravel freamwork.

I have installed social plugin, because I would like to have possibility for a sign in with Facebook account on my page.

As instruction in plugin says that:

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/ and click Create a New App in the Apps drop down.
2. Enter your Display Name (usually your site name) along with any other required fields and click Create App
3. Copy your App ID and App Secret into the fields below.
4. On the Settings tab set the Valid OAuth redirect URIs to http://www.example.com/flynsarmy/sociallogin/Facebook

So I have done each steps.

But I got stuck.

I got this when I'm trying to log into website with Facebook account in my log files(directly in back-end/settings/logs/event log :

> Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id. in
>   public_html/plugins/flynsarmy/sociallogin/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php
>   on line 169

and also when I tried to log into website with facebook account, I have redirected on my login page with `#__=__` (it could be hint to solve a problem) in the end of url.

For example if my login page is:

```
www.example.com/login
```

redirected page is:

```
www.example.com/login#__=__
```

I've read:

[HybridAuth Facebook returned an invalid user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777100/hybridauth-facebook-returned-an-invalid-user-id)

[Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102502/authentication-failed-facebook-returned-an-invalid-user-id)

[Hybridauth - PHP - Facebook returned an invalid user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068425/hybridauth-php-facebook-returned-an-invalid-user-id)

[HybridAuth Facebook returned an invalid user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777100/hybridauth-facebook-returned-an-invalid-user-id)

[laravel4 hybridauth facebook Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515618/laravel4-hybridauth-facebook-authentication-failed-facebook-returned-an-invalid)

And nothing has helped me, 
Thank You for any help info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has recently changed their API and therefore the way how they return the id is now different.

If you can manually update the hybridauth library in the plugin then it should solve the issue, otherwise you will need to report to plugin author and ask him to update hybridauth library in the plugin.