# facebook graph api issue from 2.2 to 2.3

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, symfony-2.8

My graph api automatically got upgraded from 2.2 to 2.3 and now creates a redirect loop after facebook login rather than redirecting to the redirect uri mentioned.
I am using facebook/php-sdk version 3.2.*
and graph api version is 2.3

My graph api got upgraded to version 2.3 and resulted in a redirect loop after facebook login.My user information is not saved in database as well.

I followed the solutions mentioned in here in the post:

[facebook graph api not work from 2.2 to 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994019/facebook-graph-api-not-work-from-2-2-to-2-3/43171847#43171847)

But it did not work for me.Any help would be appreciated.I also tried a var_dump inside setExtendedAccessToken().But it is not even being called.

What can be the issue? With graph api 2.2 everything was working fine.But in 2.3 its not redirecting to the specified url.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Facebook changed the response you get that  contains the access token

Comment: Thanks..Issue resolved