# OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication returns false in facebook integration

Tags: facebook, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

I am using `MVC4` Entity Framework 4.5 for facebook integration with the website. It was working fine earlier but now it had some problem logging. I neither got any kind of exception in the code nor error in error's log. I viewed many answers on stackoverflow and other sites but nothing help me out.

This function `OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication` returns `isSuccessful` false. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: When was “earlier”, and what API version are you using? http://stackoverflow.com/q/42994019/1427878

Comment: @CBroe, we are using API version 2.8 and eariler means its around 15 days before.