# Valid OAuth redirect URIs for facebook - Django Social Auth

Tags: django, facebook, python-2.7, django-socialauth

I am referring tutorials to implement django `social-auth`, I hace successfully implemented it for Twitter and Google+ . But, in case of facebook , I am not seeing "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" which has to provided for facebook. I assume that the new developer console of facebook has this new field.

By leaving the field empty, I am still able to login but I am not getting relevent details from FB. It might be because of this "redirect URI".

[image]

I followed below tutorials

- [Tutorial 1](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html)
- [Tutorial 2](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Django/Python-Django-OAuth2-Getting-Client-ID-Application-ID-Social-Sites-Facebook-Twitter-Google.php)

I guessed that "http://localhost:8000/oauth/complete/facebook/" could be the URI looking at google+ and twitter pattern but I am still not getting email ID of user.

**Can someone please confirm the redirect URI that has been used by them for Facebook in their Django App**

Comment: If the redirect URI used in the login dialog call was not set in the app settings, you would not be able to login, it would show an error message directly in the dialog, and not let you proceed.

Comment: @CBroe : I am able to login even when I dont provide redirect URI. Its required for google n twitter but not for FB.  :(

Comment: Ah, so you mean you do not explicitly provide it on your end, in your code. Well the socialauth component is probably able to generate that by itself. Then it is more likely a case of this, that it does not correctly ask for the fields you want, as is necessary since API v2.4, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/32584850/1427878

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Django sends a **redirect_state parameter** which is **not allowed** by Facebook redirect URI policy.

Here's a simple solution:

1. Create a new backend for Facebook OAuth that don't pass redirect_state:

   ```
   from social_core.backends.facebook import FacebookOAuth2

   class CustomFacebookOauth(FacebookOAuth2):
       REDIRECT_STATE = False
   ```
2. change social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2 on your `CustomFacebookOauth` in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` of settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of headache I finally found out that it was

`https://{your_website_name}/social-auth/complete/facebook/`

e.g. `https://www.instagram.com/social-auth/complete/facebook/`

Note that `https` is made mandatory by facebook.