# Android app facebook upgrade from v2.6 to v3.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, upgrade

I have an Android app and Facebook developer portal has requested me to upgrade.

According to the API upgrade tool, it has 3 items

Items to fix to upgrade Graph API  from v2.6 to v3.0:

1. Facebook Login2.0 - In v2.7 of the API, you will need to request business_management to manage your business account. (New)
2. GET {user-id}/permissions2.0 - Starts enforcing the app's restrictions (such as country or age ) on API calls made without the application's ' appsecret_proof'in the request. (Change)
3. GET {user-id}/permissions2.0 - GET /{user-id}/conversations and GET /{page-id}/conversations will return fewer fields by default. Use the 'fields' param to explicitly ask for the set of fields you want. If you ask for an explicit set of fields, the response will not contain any extra fields that you did not ask for (Change)

its not really clear what are the steps to upgrade. Can anyone give some guidance. Thanks

Comment: what is unclear about those items? number 2 and three should be implemented already in your app anyway.

Comment: im taking over the app from someone. problem is i dont know what to do. ok, so you are saying 2 & 3 if implemented so i dont need to do anything ? how do i enforce for (no.2), and do i need to ? for no.1 what is this business account ? i am very sorry, its not so clear. would be great you can clarify, some guidance, doesnt not need to be in full detail how to go about this. tq

Comment: 1) refers to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-manager-api We don’t know if your app is using any such features, so we can’t tell you if you actually need to change anything in this regard or not. 2) Does the app _have_ any such restrictions configured in the app dashboard? If not, ignore. And 3), see https://stackoverflow.com/q/32584850/1427878

Answer (score 0):

Ok I already managed to update it just by change the version in advance setting at developers.facebook.com It looks like the thing that it told to fix in update tools just apply if you use that particular code only